# oracle select from a in memory table in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PLsql table empnos Sys.odcinumberlist. This table has many entries in it. Now in the same program I want to select from this table using

select x from table(empnos) . Now what is the x in this case .  I tried value , values among other things but to no avail.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's `COLUMN_VALUE`. e.g.

```
declare
  x sys.odcinumberlist := sys.odcinumberlist(123);
  y number;
begin
  select column_value into y from table(x);
  dbms_output.put_line(y);
end;
```